# How to forward proxy via nginx with TLS?

Tags: nginx, ssl, proxy

Is it possible to forward a SOAP call to a server through nginx and encrypt it via TLS while doing so?

A SOAP service is sending data to a target location (unencrypted) and I would like to send the data to a running nginx server (to a specified port), which encrypts and forwards it to a specified server/port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible:

```
upstream soap_server {
    server soap.server.com:443;
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass                    https://soap_server;
        proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/trusted_ca_cert.crt;
        proxy_ssl_verify        on;
        proxy_ssl_verify_depth  2;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
    }
}
```

As an alternative, you can use [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/examples.html)

```
[soap]
accept = 80
connect = soap.server.com:443
CAPath = trusted_ca.txt
```